# How to find and use Dark Zone keys?

Tags: the-division

I have three Dark Zone keys in my inventory. I took two from players and one was just there, I don't remember picking it up. **Where do you get them regularly?**

Also, I found a few chests that require these keys, but I wasn't able to open one yet because you need to be Dark Zone Level 30 to do so. **Are there any chests for Dark Zone levels lower than 30?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are dropping randomly when killing npcs in the dark zone. When you kill another player his collected dark zone keys can drop.

They are used to open special chests, which can only be accessed with those keys.

Edit:
In [this post](http://www.accelerated-ideas.com/thedivision/how-to-get-dark-zones-keys-and-open-chests.aspx) you can see some pictures, how these chests look like.
If you found any, there is a chance, it is available to open (thats not the case every time). And they can only be looted by the tean/player, who opened it.
For others the chest is not interactive.

Comment: Are you sure there are no key chests below rank 30? I've seen 30+ chests and I've seen key chests. I don't remember for sure if I've actually run into a key chest while I had a key, but I don't think it required rank 30 to use.

Comment: There are most definitely chests under rank 30. I've used all of mine and I'm only dz rank 19.

Comment: Updated the answer. I couldnt remember, if i opened those chests below DZ 30.

Comment: Rank 10 chests exist, though they're not found as frequently as rank 30s.  I haven't come across any others at different ranks though.